# CRON и скрипт не работают вместе

Tags: python, pdf, cron

Имею скрипт на питоне, который в консоли из окружения отрабатывает на ура
запуск скрипта в консоли:

```
cd /root/bill
source bin/activate
puthon filegen.py
```

Сам скрипт имеет логику: бежим по таблице в монго, получаем HTML, генерим из него PDF и грохаем запись, как выполненную:

```
#!/root/bill/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from mongoengine import *
import datetime
import time
import calendar

from io import BytesIO as IO
import gzip

import pdfkit
import pytils

from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

import sys
import random
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')

connect(host='mongodb://main:PWD@HOST/bill?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE') 
    
class Genq(Document):
    dokstring = StringField()
    outpdf = StringField()

print ("started")

foreva = True

while foreva:
    print ("....")
    reqs = Genq.objects()
    for doc in reqs:    
        print ("++++++")
        pdfkit.from_string(doc.dokstring, doc.outpdf)
        print (">>>>>>")
        doc.delete()
        print ("!!!!!!!")
```

Пытаюсь запустить этот вечный скрипт в кроне командой:

```
@reboot /root/bill/bin/python /root/bill/filegen.py >>/var/log/syslof
```

Получаю в консоли следующее сообщение:

```
root@bill2:~# tail 50 /var/log/syslog
tail: cannot open ‘50’ for reading: No such file or directory
==> /var/log/syslog <==
started
....
++++++
Jul 22 04:26:56 bill2 postfix/pickup[1115]: C16891600F3: uid=0 from=<root>
Jul 22 04:26:56 bill2 postfix/cleanup[1263]: C16891600F3: message-id=<20160722082656.C16891600F3@bill2>
Jul 22 04:26:56 bill2 postfix/qmgr[1116]: C16891600F3: from=<root@bill2>, size=1221, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 22 04:26:56 bill2 postfix/local[1265]: C16891600F3: to=<root@bill2>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jul 22 04:26:56 bill2 postfix/qmgr[1116]: C16891600F3: removed
Jul 22 04:27:00 bill2 ntpdate[603]: step time server 91.189.89.198 offset -0.344170 sec
Jul 22 04:27:16 bill2 ntpdate[1281]: adjust time server 91.189.89.198 offset -0.000024 sec
root@bill2:~#
```

Насколько я понимаю скрипт уходит куда-то в себя на строке:

```
pdfkit.from_string(doc.dokstring, doc.outpdf)
```

Но почему из консоли то отрабатывает как нужно?

Все что я понял, так это то, что дело в том, что у крона какое то свое окружение, из которого то ли не видна файловая система, то ли не видна библиотека `pdfkit`, хотя я все запускаю от рута.

Comment: Может там какое исключение, стоит добавить catch и вывести его.

Comment: изменил код на 

    `for doc in reqs:    
        print ("++++++")
        try:
         pdfkit.from_string(doc.dokstring, doc.outpdf)
         doc.delete()
         print ("!!!!!!!")

        except:
          print (">>>>>>")

и получил в консоли набор >>>>>

как теперь понять в чем именно исключение?

Comment: ага, нашел вывод ошибки:
root@bill2:~# tail 50 /var/log/syslog
tail: cannot open ‘50’ for reading: No such file or directory
==> /var/log/syslog <==
>>>>>>
(u'Unexpected error:', <type 'exceptions.IOError'>)
....
++++++
>>>>>>
(u'Unexpected error:', <type 'exceptions.IOError'>)
....
++++++
>>>>>>

Comment: Поигрался с созданием файлов  
попробовал команду `os.mknod('/var/www/output/123.pdf')`  
при запуске в консоли - создает, ребутаю, запускается через крон и выбрасывает опять .IOError  

    права на /var/www/output/ три семерки

Comment: sytemd unit сделай с Restart=always, и про python venv почитай

Comment: А вообще сделай так: `@reboot  export PYTHONPATH=/root/bill && /root/bill/bin/python /root/bill/filegen.py >>/var/log/syslof`

Answer (score 4):

Судя по строке `source bin/activate` - вы используете `virtualenv` или его форк/клон. `virtualenv` - это отдельное окружение с другими путями, в котором могут быть установлены модули, которые отсутствуют в системном питоне (кот. запускается по-умолчанию для всех UNIX пользователей)

Поэтому сделайте wrapper-file, в котором можно установить правильное окружение:

run_me.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export VIRTUAL_ENV=/root/bill
cd $VIRTUAL_ENV
source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate
$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python /path/to/filegen.py
```

и запускайте его из `CRONTAB`'а

Comment: Если я размещу run_me.sh в /root, то строка в кроне должна быть такая:
@reboot /root/run_me.sh ?

и еще, нужно ли делать
chmod -x /root/run_me.sh

?

Comment: UPD1:
Разместил файл sh в var
Поменял строчку в кроне на @reboot /var/fs.sh >>/var/log/syslog/

вижу в логе:
Jul 22 06:36:13 bill2 CRON[982]: (root) CMD (/var/fs.sh >>/var/log/syslog)

Но ничего не произошло((

Comment: @СебульбаКасторский, конечно надо дать права на выполнение `chmod 770 run_me.sh`

Comment: @СебульбаКасторский, если я правильно понимаю `@reboot` - CRON запустит ваш скрипт единожды после рестарта (`reboot`) машины. На этапе тестирования есть смысл использовать запуск по расписанию

Comment: Весьма интересно.. попробовал просто так запустить скрипт
`bash fs.sh`

получил следующее:
<br/>
root@bill2:/var# bash fs.sh
: No such file or directoryll
: No such file or directory<br/>
/bin/python: No such file or directory
root@bill2:/var# ^C


Получается что система не видит какую то папку?

Comment: [запостите](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/547336/edit) содержание `fs.sh`...

Comment: #!/bin/bash
    export VIRTUAL_ENV=/root/bill
    cd $VIRTUAL_ENV
    source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate
    $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python $VIRTUAL_ENV/filegen.py

Comment: а как выглядит полная строка в CRONTAB?

Comment: @reboot /var/fs.sh >>/var/log/syslog


собственно она там одна

Comment: замените `#!/bin/bash` на `#!/bin/bash -x` и запустите `fs.sh` еще раз - у вас будет подробный output, где будет понятно на каком шаге возникает ошибка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42871/discussion-between---and-maxu).